# Having issues with JavaScript AutoComplete

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I am trying to get AutoComplete to work on a website application I am making.  I have stripped my code down to the bare essentials and I still cannot get it to work.  I got the source file from http://www.phpguru.org/static/AutoComplete.html and I have done my best to implement it exactly how they did on their website demo.  My test code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <title>test</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Management/AutoComplete.js"></script>

        <div id="content">  

            <script type="text/javascript">

                if (location.href.indexOf('/JavaScripts/AutoComplete') != -1) {

                    window.onload = function(){

                        data = ['Joes Plumbing1','Joes Plumbing2','Joes Plumbing3','Joes Plumbing4'].sort();    

                        AutoComplete_Create('customers', data);

                    }

                }

            </script>

            <form id="form" action="" method="post">

                <table border="0">

                    <tr>
                        <td>Customer Search</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" id="customers"/></td>
                    </tr>

                </table>

            </form>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

**Here is a bit more back ground info that may help you help me:**

My server works fine with other `.js` files.

I copied and pasted the `AutoComplete.js` (NOT `AutoComplete.old.js`) file I downloaded from the site mentioned above, and didn't touch it at all.

**Why isn't this working?**

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: No error at all.  The page source (from the browser) looks good too, or at least I cannot see any problems with it.  My page generates with a search bar, but when I type in it, or double click it, no AutoComplete function occurs.

Comment: if location.href.indexOf('/JavaScripts/AutoComplete') != -1) - this means the URL of your autocomplete page must contain the specified string. Does it?

Comment: That was the problem, I thought that line was asking for the location of the AutoComplete.js file kind of like the the <script> tag did.  I now realize I wasted about 3 hours of my life because I am retarded.  Please answer my question so I can give you some points @Goran!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Goran answered my question correctly in his comment to my question so props to him.  The problem was my `if` statement:

`if (location.href.indexOf('/JavaScripts/AutoComplete') != -1)`

Once I made the string `/JavaScripts/AutoComplete` match what was in my address bar everything worked fine!